# Leer archivos, y generar un archivo de texto en java

Tags: java

buenos dias, estoy realizando una adecuación en un desarrollo, lo que pasa es que estoy leyendo información de 2 archivos de texto que tienen como extensión .n0 y .n1, ambos archivos requiero que se lean y generen un solo archivo con la unificación de ambos como estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que actualmente generan archivos dependiendo el numero que se encuentren en la ruta donde están alojados, en este ejemplo son 2 pero así pueden ser mas dependiendo, la idea es que si por ejemplo hay 2 archivos solo genere 1 solo, agrego el siguiente codigo:

```
/**
     * 
     * METODO validaReporte
     * ::: VALIDA LA INFORMACIï¿½N DE LOS REPORTES BES */
    public static boolean validaReporte(String rutaReporte, String nombreReporte, Map<Integer, String> mapDir, String correos, int limiteErrores) {
        boolean resultado = true;
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
//      LISTA PARA ALMACENAR ERRORES DE LAYOUT
        ArrayList<String> errorLayout = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
//          APERTURA DE REPORTE
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(rutaReporte);
            DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(fileInput);
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInput));
            String linea = "";
            long numLinea = 0L;
            boolean continuaLectura = true;
            List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagos = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
            List<LayoutCPBES> excepcionesPagos = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
            LayoutCPBES layoutPagos = new LayoutCPBES();
            ComplementoPagoBES cPago = new ComplementoPagoBES();
            while ((linea = buffer.readLine()) != null && continuaLectura) {
                cPago = new ComplementoPagoBES();
                String separador = Pattern.quote("|");
                String [] parts = linea.split(separador);
                String excepcionLayout = "";
                numLinea++;
                try {
//                  # LINEA DE ARCHIVO LEIDO
                    cPago.setNumLinea(String.valueOf(numLinea));
//                  LAYOUT PAGO
                    cPago.setLayoutPago(linea);
                    cPago.setCtaQueFactura((parts[0].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[0])));
                    cPago.setFechaPago(parts[18].trim());
                    cPago.setNumLotePago((parts[23].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[23])));
                    cPago.setTipoLotePago(parts[24].trim());
                    cPago.setSecuenciaLotePago((parts[25].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[25])));
                    cPago.setCtaNacional((parts[1].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[1])));
                    cPago.setCtaConsolidada((parts[2].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[2])));
                    cPago.setCtaIndividual((parts[3].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[3])));
                    cPago.setFechaCorte(parts[4].trim());
                    cPago.setTipoDocumento(parts[5].trim());
                    cPago.setRegion(parts[6].trim());
                    cPago.setNumTelefono((parts[7].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[7])));
                    cPago.setUuidRelacionado(parts[8].trim());
                    cPago.setNumParcialidad((parts[9].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[9])));
                    cPago.setSeqNumFineq((parts[10].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[10].trim())));
                    cPago.setSaldoAnterior((parts[11].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[11])));
                    cPago.setImporte((parts[12].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[12])));
                    cPago.setSaldoInsoluto((parts[13].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[13])));
                    cPago.setSerie(parts[19].trim());
                    cPago.setFolio((parts[20].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Long.parseLong(parts[20])));
                    cPago.setImeiSacPhone((parts[21].trim().equals("") ? "0" : parts[21].trim()));
                    cPago.setImeiFineq((parts[22].trim().equals("") ? "0" : parts[22].trim()));
                    cPago.setMetodoPagoM2k(parts[26].trim());
                    cPago.setNombreCliente(parts[27].replaceAll("[\\s*\\*\\s*\\s+]+" , " ").trim());                                
                    cPago.setRfcReceptor(parts[28].trim());
                    cPago.setOrigenPago(parts[32].trim());
                    cPago.setUsuarioPago(parts[33].trim());
                    cPago.setAcctId(parts[34].trim());
                    cPago.setEstatusPago(parts[35].trim());
                    cPago.setFechaCreacionBES(parts[36].trim());
                    cPago.setIndGenCp(Constantes.NO);
                    cPago.setInconsisDatos(Constantes.SI);
                    // AGREGADOS                    
                    cPago.setDomFiscal(parts[29].trim());//prueba 1 ojo no
                    cPago.setCodPostal((parts[30].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(parts[30].trim())));
                    cPago.setClaveRegFiscal(parts[31].trim());
                    cPago.setTasa((parts[14].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[14].trim())));
                    cPago.setExento((parts[16].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[16].trim())));
                    
                    //JJ 
                    cPago.setDescTasa(parts[15].trim());
                    cPago.setDescExento(parts[17].trim());
                    //JJ
                    
                    //cPago.setImporteIva((parts[14].trim().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(parts[14].trim())));
                    // AGREGADOS
                    layoutPagos = new LayoutCPBES();
                    layoutPagos.setListDocumentoRelacionado(cPago);
                    lstPagos.add(layoutPagos);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (!linea.equals("")) {
                        LOG.error("[TBVRB] Error en el reporte " + nombreReporte + " la linea " + numLinea
                                + " no coincide con el layout :: Error>>>{" + linea + "}", e);
                        excepcionLayout = "# Linea :: ["+numLinea+"]"+" Cuenta --->> "+cPago.getCtaQueFactura()+"\n{"+linea+"}\nError presentado --->>>["+e+"]\n";
//                      SE ALMACENAN LOS REGISTROS DEL LAYOUT QUE PRESENTAN ERRORES
                        errorLayout.add(excepcionLayout);
                        layoutPagos = new LayoutCPBES();
                        layoutPagos.setListDocumentoRelacionado(cPago);
                        excepcionesPagos.add(layoutPagos);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
//          CIERRE DE REPORTE
            dataInput.close();
            
            if (excepcionesPagos != null && excepcionesPagos.size() > limiteErrores) {
                String mensaje = "";
                LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se sobre paso el limite de errores por layout en el reporte " + nombreReporte+", se encontraron "+errorLayout.size()+" errores");
                mensaje = "EL REPORTE "+nombreReporte+" SOBRE PASO EL LIMITE DE ERRORES POR LAYOUT... \n";
                mensaje += "\nSE MOVIO EL ARCHIVO A LA CARPETA ERRORES: "+mapDir.get(6);
                mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
                Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Se sobre paso el limite de errores por layout en el reporte "+nombreReporte, mensaje, correos);
                return false;
                
            }else {
                if (lstPagos != null && lstPagos.size() > 0) {
                    LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se encontro un total de " + lstPagos.size() + " pagos, sobre pagos y/o reversos en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
                    LOG.info("[TBVRB] " + lstPagos.size() + " pagos, sobre pagos y/o reversos del reporte " + nombreReporte
                            + " se procesaran para validar inconsistencias");
                    List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagosValidados = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
                    lstPagosValidados = validaReporte(lstPagos, nombreReporte, correos, limiteErrores,mapDir);
                    LOG.info("[TBVRB] Termina validaciï¿½n de inconsistencias " + nombreReporte);
                    if (lstPagosValidados != null && lstPagosValidados.size() > 0) {
                        if (generaReportes(excepcionesPagos, lstPagosValidados, mapDir, nombreReporte, errorLayout, correos)) {
                            resultado = true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        resultado = false;
                    }
                    
                }else {
                    if (excepcionesPagos != null && excepcionesPagos.size() > 0) {
                        if (generaReportes(excepcionesPagos, null, mapDir, nombreReporte, errorLayout, correos)) {
                            resultado = true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        String mensaje = "";
                        LOG.info("[TBVRB] El reporte " + nombreReporte + " no tiene informaciï¿½n");
                        mensaje = "EL REPORTE "+nombreReporte+" NO TIENE INFORMACIï¿½N... \n";
                        mensaje += "\nSE MOVIO EL REPORTE A LA CARPETA ERRORES: "+mapDir.get(6);
                        mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
                        Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Reporte "+nombreReporte + " sin informaciï¿½n", mensaje, correos);
                        resultado = false;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("[TBVRB] Ocurrio una excepciï¿½n en la lectura del reporte " + nombreReporte, e);
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

---

```
/**
     * METODO GENERA REPORTES
     * ::: GENERA LOS REPORTES PARA GENERAR CP, PARA REVISAR POR INCONSISTENCIAS Y ERRORES DE LAYOUT
     *
     * */
    public static boolean generaReportes(List<LayoutCPBES> excepcionesPagos, List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagos, Map<Integer, String> mapDir, String nombreReporte, ArrayList<String> errorLayout, String correos) throws CpagoTBException {
        boolean respuesta = false;
        int reporteExcepcion = 0;
        List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagosExcepciones = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
        List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagosInconsistencias = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
        List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagosOk = new ArrayList<LayoutCPBES>();
        ArrayList<String> reportes = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        
        LOG.info("[TBVRB] Inicia validaciï¿½n de excepciones por errores de layout en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
        if (errorLayout != null && errorLayout.size() > 0) {
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se presentaron "+errorLayout.size()+" excepciones en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Comienza validaciï¿½n de registros afectados por errores de layout en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
//          [<] SE BUSCAN PAGOS QUE SE ENCUENTREN EN LOTE DE ERRORES DE LAYOUT
            if (excepcionesPagos != null && excepcionesPagos.size() > 0) {
                for (LayoutCPBES layoutExcepciones : excepcionesPagos) {
                    for (LayoutCPBES layoutCPBES : lstPagos) {
                        if (layoutExcepciones.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura() == layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura()
                                && layoutExcepciones.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago().trim().equals(layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago().trim())
                                && layoutExcepciones.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago() == layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago()
                                && layoutExcepciones.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago().trim().equals(layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago())
                                && layoutExcepciones.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago() == layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago()) {
                            lstPagosExcepciones.add(layoutCPBES);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            String mensaje = "";
            if (lstPagosExcepciones != null && lstPagosExcepciones.size() > 0) {
                reporteExcepcion = 1;
                LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se encontraron "+lstPagosExcepciones.size()+" registros afectados por errores de layout en el reporte " + nombreReporte +" que seran removidos");
                mensaje="EL REPORTE BES " + nombreReporte + " PRESENTO ERRORES DE LAYOUT EN LAS SIGUIENTES LINEAS: \n";
                for (int i = 0; i < errorLayout.size(); i++) {
                    mensaje += "\n"+errorLayout.get(i);
                }
                mensaje += "\n\n\nSE REMOVERAN LOS SIGUIENTES REGISTROS DEL REPORTE "+ nombreReporte +" POR PERTENECER AL LOTE DE REGISTROS CON ERRORES DE LAYOUT: \n";
                for (LayoutCPBES layoutCPBES : lstPagosExcepciones) {
                    mensaje +=  "\n# Linea :: ["+layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLinea()+"] Cuenta --->>>"+layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura()+"\n{"+layoutCPBES.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString()+"}\n";
                }
                mensaje += "\n\nSE GENERO REPORTE CON LOS REGISTROS QUE PRESENTARON ERRORES POR LAYOUT EN LA RUTA: "+ mapDir.get(5);
                mensaje += "\n\nLA NOMENCLATURA DEL REPORTE ES: "+nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "")+"_E_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt ";
                mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
                Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Errores de layout y exclusion de registros en archivo " + nombreReporte, mensaje, correos);
                lstPagos.removeAll(lstPagosExcepciones);
                
            }else {
                LOG.info("[TBVRB] No se encontraron registros afectados por errores de layout del reporte " + nombreReporte);
                mensaje="EL REPORTE " + nombreReporte + " PRESENTO ERRORES DE LAYOUT EN LAS SIGUIENTES LINEAS: \n";
                LOG.error(mensaje);
                for (int i = 0; i < errorLayout.size(); i++) {
                    mensaje +="\n"+errorLayout.get(i);
                }
                mensaje += "\n\nSE GENERO REPORTE CON LOS REGISTROS QUE PRESENTARON ERRORES POR LAYOUT EN LA RUTA: "+ mapDir.get(5);
                mensaje += "\n\nLA NOMENCLATURA DEL REPORTE ES: "+nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "")+"_E_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt ";
                mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
                Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Errores de layout presentados en reporte "+nombreReporte, mensaje, correos);
            }
            reportes.add(Constantes.R_EXCEPCIONES);
        }else {
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] No se encontraron excepciones por errores de layout en el reporte  " + nombreReporte);
        }


//      SE BUSCAN PAGOS QUE PRESENTAN INCONSISTENCIAS
        for(LayoutCPBES lstPagosValidados : lstPagos) {
            /*F
            INCONSIS   N
            DATOSFISCALES  S*/
           //VALIDA QUE NO TENGA INCONSISTENCIAS, QUE SI TENGA DATOS FISCALES SIN IMPORTAR QUE SEA FACTURA O FINANCIAMIENTO
            //YA QUE AL NO TENER INCONSISTENCIAS Y TENER SUS DATOS FISCALES (SERIE, FOLIO Y UUID) 
            //INDICA QUE TODO ESTÃ BIEN, SE AGREGA A PAGOSOK
            if (lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getInconsisDatos().equals(Constantes.NO)
             &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDatosFiscales().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.SI)) {
                //LOG.info("generaReportes primer if se agrega a OK");
                //LOG.info("generaReportes registro: "+lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString());
                lstPagosOk.add(lstPagosValidados);
            }
            //VALIDA QUE TENGA INCONSISTENCIAS, QUE SI TENGA DATOS FISCALES SIN IMPORTAR QUE SEA FACTURA O FINANCIAMIENTO
            //YA QUE AL TENER INCONSISTENCIAS Y TENER SUS DATOS FISCALES (SERIE, FOLIO Y UUID), HABLAMOS DE UN ERROR QUE SI SE PUEDE Y DEBE 
            //REPORTAR, SE AGREGA A INCONSISTENCIAS
            else if (lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getInconsisDatos().equals(Constantes.SI)
            &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDatosFiscales().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.SI)){
                //LOG.info("generaReportes primer else if se agrega a INCONSISTENCIAS");
                //LOG.info("generaReportes registro: "+lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString());
                lstPagosInconsistencias.add(lstPagosValidados);
            }
            //VALIDA QUE TENGA INCONSISTENCIAS, QUE NO TENGA DATOS FISCALES Y SEA UNA FACTURA, 
            //YA QUE SE DEBE DE REPORTAR CUANDO LA FACTURA TENGA ERROR POR LOS DATOS FISCALES, SE AGREGA A INCONSISTENCIAS
            else if (lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getInconsisDatos().equals(Constantes.SI)
                &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDatosFiscales().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.NO)
                &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.SERVICIOTELECOMUNICACION)) {
                    //LOG.info("generaReportes segundo else if se agrega a AMBOS");
                    //LOG.info("generaReportes registro: "+lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString());
                    lstPagosOk.add(lstPagosValidados);
                    lstPagosInconsistencias.add(lstPagosValidados);
            }
            //VALIDA QUE TENGA INCONSISTENCIAS, QUE NO TENGA DATOS FISCALES Y QUE SEA UN FINANCIAMIENTO
            //YA QUE LAS INCONSISTENCIAS POR TENER SUS DATOS FISCALES (SERIE, FOLIO Y UUID) DEL FINANCIAMIENTO
            //NO SE DEBEN DE REPORTAR Y SE DEBEN DE CARGAR A LA BASE DE DATOS, SE AGREGA A PAGOSOK
            else if (lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getInconsisDatos().equals(Constantes.SI)
            &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDatosFiscales().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.NO)
            &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.FINANCIAMIENTO)){
                //LOG.info("generaReportes tercer if se agrega a OK");
                //LOG.info("generaReportes registro: "+lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString());
                lstPagosOk.add(lstPagosValidados);
            }   
            //VALIDA QUE TENGA INCONSISTENCIAS, QUE NO TENGA DATOS FISCALES Y QUE SEA UN FINANCIAMIENTO
            //YA QUE LAS INCONSISTENCIAS POR TENER SUS DATOS FISCALES (SERIE, FOLIO Y UUID) DEL FINANCIAMIENTO
            //NO SE DEBEN DE REPORTAR Y SE DEBEN DE CARGAR A LA BASE DE DATOS, SE AGREGA A PAGOSOK
            else if (lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getInconsisDatos().equals(Constantes.SI)
            &&lstPagosValidados.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDatosFiscales().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.SINO)){
                //LOG.info("generaReportes cuarto else if se agrega a INCONSISTENCIAS");

                lstPagosInconsistencias.add(lstPagosValidados);
            }   
            
        }
        
//      SE VALIDA SI SE GENERA REPORTE DE INCONSISTENCIAS
        if (lstPagosInconsistencias != null && lstPagosInconsistencias.size() > 0) {
            reportes.add(Constantes.R_INCOSISTENCIAS);
        }
        
//      SE VALIDA SI SE GENERA REPORTE SIN INCONSISTENCIAS
        if (lstPagosOk != null && lstPagosOk.size() > 0) {
            LOG.info("lstPagosOk JJ... " + lstPagosOk.size());

            reportes.add(Constantes.R_OK);//JJ
            
            LOG.info("lstPagosOk ADD JJ... " + lstPagosOk.size());
            LOG.info("lstPagosOk ADD JJ... " + reportes.size());
        }
        
        if (reportes != null && reportes.size() > 0) {
            
            LOG.info("[reportes... JJ " + reportes);
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Inicia generaciï¿½n de reportes del archivo " + nombreReporte);
            Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
            String archivo = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < reportes.size(); i++) {

                LOG.info("ReportesSize JJ.. " + reportes.size());
                String fechaReporte = FECHA_EXPEDICION.format(fecha.getTime());
                switch (reportes.get(i)) {
                case Constantes.R_EXCEPCIONES:
                    archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_E_" + fechaReporte + ".txt";
                    if (reporteExcepcion == 1) {
                        excepcionesPagos.addAll(lstPagosExcepciones);
                        if (generaReporte(excepcionesPagos, mapDir.get(5), archivo)) {
                            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se genero el reporte con excepciones " + archivo +" del archivo " + nombreReporte);
                            respuesta = true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (generaReporte(excepcionesPagos, mapDir.get(5), archivo)) {
                            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se genero el reporte con excepciones " + archivo +" del archivo " + nombreReporte);
                            respuesta = true;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    break;

                case Constantes.R_INCOSISTENCIAS:
                    archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_I_" + fechaReporte + ".txt";
                    if (generaReporte(lstPagosInconsistencias, mapDir.get(5), archivo)) {
                        LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se genero el reporte con inconsistencias " + archivo +" del archivo " + nombreReporte);
                        respuesta = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Constantes.R_OK:
                    //archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_CP_" + fechaReporte + ".txt";
                    archivo = nombreReporte;
                    if (generaReporte(lstPagosOk, mapDir.get(4), archivo)) {
                        LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se genero el reporte con pagos, sobre pagos y/o reversos " + archivo +" del archivo " + nombreReporte);
                        respuesta = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

---

```
public static boolean generaReporte(List<LayoutCPBES> lstReporte, String ruta, String nombreReporte) {
        boolean resultado = false;
        String cdena ="";
        FileWriter writer;
        String nuevaLinea ="";
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(ruta + nombreReporte);
            String folio ="";
            for (LayoutCPBES lstPagos : lstReporte) {
                
//              if(lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal().length()>=116) {
//                  System.out.println("QUE pedo...............");
//                  nuevaLinea+= lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal().substring(0, 115);
//                  
//              }
//              
                
                nuevaLinea = lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaNacional()+"|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaConsolidada() + "|" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaIndividual()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCorte() + "|"+ lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRegion()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumTelefono()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUuidRelacionado()+"|"+ lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumParcialidad() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSeqNumFineq()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoAnterior()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImporte() + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()
                        //nuevos campos jj                              
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTasa()                     
                        
                        //Campos donde viene TASA(descripcion en el archivo, puede o no venir TASA)
                        //+ "|" +""
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDescTasa()                                                         
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getExento()
                        //CAMPO DONDE VIENE EXENTO (descripcion en el archivo, puede o no venir EXENTO)
                        +"|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDescExento()
                        //nuevos campos jj                                              
                        + "|" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSerie()
                        + "|" +     lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio() 
                        + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImeiSacPhone() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImeiFineq() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago() + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNombreCliente()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRfcReceptor()
                        //Nuevos campos jj
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal()                        
                        //+ "|" + cdena
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCodPostal()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getClaveRegFiscal()
                        //nuevos campos jj
                        
                        + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getOrigenPago() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUsuarioPago()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getAcctId()
                        + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getEstatusPago() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCreacionBES();
                lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setLayoutPago(nuevaLinea);
                writer.write(lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getLayoutPago() + System.lineSeparator());
                //LOG.info("fOLIO SIN LOS 0" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio());
            }
            writer.close();
            resultado = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("[TBVRB] Ocurrio una excepción al generar el reporte" + nombreReporte, e);
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Como dato adicional en esta parte del codigo del case es donde ya hace todo el proceso para generar los archivo ya que ahi se ejecuta el metodo generaReporte:

```
case Constantes.R_OK:
            //archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_CP_" + fechaReporte + ".txt";
            archivo = nombreReporte;
            if (generaReporte(lstPagosOk, mapDir.get(4), archivo)) {
                LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se genero el reporte con pagos, sobre pagos y/o reversos " + archivo +" del archivo " + nombreReporte);
                respuesta = true;
            }
            break;
        }
```

El procesamiento lo hace bien pero solo es el problema que no unifica todo.Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, si hay algo que haga falta por poner con gusto lo podré para hacer mas entendible. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos. Tengo una duda. Porque estas reemplazando el nombre del archivo de .txt a otro formato? /* archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_I_" + fechaReporte + ".txt"; */. Creo que deberías concatenar la información que quieres y al final colocar el .txt en lugar de intentar usar la función replace.

Comment: Hola Ernesto, la verdad si tienes mucha razón lo que pasa es que esa parte no la estoy ocupando, ya que el nombre del archivo se debe quedar igual, anterior lo tenía así: "archivo = nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "") + "_CP_" + fechaReporte + ".txt";" ya que había otro proceso donde toma el toma el nombre de la nomenclatura para hacer otra acción pero esa está deshabilitado ya que se requiere que quede así: BPNR0620230717125926.txt (uniendo lo que tiene n0 y n1)